# Realloc get wrong

Tags: c, realloc

I have 3 fields of data which are separated by a ",". I use wcstok to separate them
b is a double pointer, which is reallocated when a new element was founded by wcstok.
When using realloc b with first element "I am a college student", it worked normally. But when pc pointed to second element "I live in Canada". b can't be reallocated.

```
int n = 0;
wchar_t a[] = L"I am a college student, I live in Canada, I love ice cream";
wchar_t** b = NULL;
wchar_t** temp2 = NULL;

wchar_t* pc = wcstok(a, L",");

while (pc)
{
    n++;
    temp2 = (wchar_t**)realloc(b, n * sizeof(wchar_t*));

    if (!temp2)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            free(b[k]);
            b[k] = NULL;
        }
        free(*b);
        *b = NULL;
    }

    b = temp2;

    b[n - 1] = (wchar_t*)malloc(((wcslen(pc)+1) * sizeof(wchar_t)));
    wcsncpy(b[n-1], pc, 1000);
    b[n - 1][wcslen(pc)] = '\0';

    pc = wcstok(NULL, L",");
}
```

Comment: `wchar_t** b = NULL;` and `n=0;` then `temp2 = (wchar_t**)realloc(b, n * sizeof(wchar_t*));` will allocate How Many Bytes from What Address?  (hint: you can't `realloc NULL` to `0`)

Comment: don't use `wchar_t` by the way. don't cast return of malloc function family.

Comment: What do you mean by "b can't be reallocated"? Realloc may return the same address... So what's wrong exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin use to count how much memory I want to realloc b. In while loop, I have increase n. And I belive that nothing wrong with casting realloc in this situation

Comment: I call "b can't be reallocated" because I run line by line a see that, b hasn't get any thing new when  wcsncpy(b[n-1], pc, 1000); was called. I should copy "I live in Canada" but nothing happen. And it crashed  b[n - 1][wcslen(pc)] = '\0'; was called

Comment: `wcstok` seems to need three arguments.

Comment: There is *never* "nothing wrong with casting" `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`. Those functions are defined to return a pointer type which will be implicitly converted to any other pointer type, but **if you (mistakenly) omit their prototypes** then cast will likely suppress the helpful warning the compiler would have provided. By The Way, you have omitted prototypes from your sample code.

Comment: Your sample code does not test the return value of your memory allocation functions. Please describe how you can possibly know whether they succeeded or failed. (Hint: you can't.)

Comment: regarding: `if (!temp2)
    {
    ...

    }

    b = temp2;`  will result (when `realloc` fails) with `b` being assigned `NULL`.  Then the code starts referencing the `fields` of `b` which will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions, `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `wcsncpy(b[n-1], pc, 1000);`  There is NOT any 1000 characters available to copy into.  Suggest using the function: `wcslen()` +1 to obtain the correct length